# A pair of dice is thrown 180 times in a row. Define random variable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

A pair of dice is thrown 180 times in a row. Find the probability that (the total on the two dice is seven), happens at least 25 times.

My question is how can I define random variable $X$ in verbal way?

Let $X$ shows the two numbers that come when a pair of dice is rolled 180 times or Let $X$ denote the sum of the incoming numbers?

Answer (score 1):

*X* should denote the sum of the numbers thrown. After that you can use probability distribution.